# Three.js material.skinning = true causes shader compilation error

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to skin a dynamic geometry but after adding

```
material.skinning = true
```

I get a shader compilation error which states "too many uniforms".

I already found [this Github Issue](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/5129) but it is closed and doesn't propose a solution.
I generally understand the problem but as my Object neither has much geometry, nor bones I don't understand how that many uniforms (>1024 according to my Max Uniform Vectors [here](http://doesmybrowsersupportwebgl.com/)) can be added only because of `skinning=true`

My code:

```
var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0xAABBAA, skinning: true});
var maxLength = Math.max(geom.vertices[0].y, geom.vertices[geom.vertices.length-1].y);

        // calculate skinweigths
        for(var i = 0; i < MAXRESOLUTION; i++){
            var skinIndex = geom.vertices[i].y > 0? 1 : 0;
            var skinWeight = Math.abs(geom.vertices[i].y/maxLength);

            geom.skinIndices.push( new THREE.Vector4( skinIndex, skinIndex + 1, 0, 0 ) );
            geom.skinWeights.push( new THREE.Vector4( 1 - skinWeight, skinWeight, 0, 0 ) );
        }

        // create new mesh
        var newMesh = new THREE.SkinnedMesh(geom, material);

        skeleton.bones[0].position.y = geom.vertices[0].y;
        skeleton.bones[1].position.y = -geom.vertices[0].y;

        // combine mesh with skeleton
        var root = skeleton.bones[0];
        newMesh.add(root);

        newMesh.bind(skeleton);
```

Thank you :)

r75

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was: I attached the material (with `skinned=true`) to a normal Mesh, not a SkinnedMesh.

Due to simplification I actually didn't include this in the code example above.